# Browser Javascript AWS Translation example

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, translate

I am trying to find a practical example of using the Javascript (not Node JS or React, browser Javascript) AWS API to Translate text from English to another language. I have downloaded the aws-sdk-2.211.0.min.js version of the API and have verified that it does include Translate. I have the IAM user set up with the correct permissions. I just need an example of how to add my IAM key and secrete and call the Translate function of the AWS Javascript API version 2.211.0. I have searched on here and found some things close to what I need, but have not yet found something that would work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you might be able to get some information out of this: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-translate-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/examples-twitch.md